# Loop through variables in task that has another list embedded in the variables

Tags: ansible

I am looking to loop through a list of variables.  I have it looping through the of variables using with_items, however the catch is there is a list within that variables list that needs to have a different subset / number of variables that i need to iterate through as well.

I have tried different filters to include with_nested, with_subelements, and with_items.  I know that they are moving towards loops as the primary driver moving forward so any solution ideally would leverage the ansible path moving forward.  I am looking at having an "inner" loop or an external task that will iterate through the vlans_list and input that data as its to that point.

group Variables

```
vnic_templates:
   - name: vNIC-A
     fabric: A
     mac_pool: testmac1 
     mtu: 1500 
     org_dn: org-root
     redundancy_type: none 
     state: present
     template_type: initial-template
     vlans_list:          ### THE PROBLEM CHILD
       - name: vlan2
         native: 'no'
         state: present
       - name: vlan3
         native: 'no'
         state: present
```

The actual task - i have issues when i have to input multiple vlans.  The vnic template will have a 1 to one relationship however the vlans_list could be 1 vnic_template to many vlans.

```
  ucs_vnic_template:
    hostname: "{{ ucs_manager_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ ucs_manager_username }}"
    password: "{{ ucs_manager_password }}"
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    fabric: "{{ item.fabric }}"
    mac_pool: "{{ item.mac_pool }}"
    mtu: "{{ item.mtu }}"
    org_dn: "{{ item.org_dn }}"
    redundancy_type: "{{ item.redundancy_type }}"
    state: "{{ item.state }}"
    template_type: "{{ item.template_type }}"
    vlans_list: 
     - name: "{{ item.1.name }}"
       native: "{{ item.1.native }}"
       state: "{{ item.1.present }}"  
#    loop: "{{ vnic_templates | subelements('vlans_list') }}"
    with_items:
     - "{{ vnic_templates }}"
```

I am starting down the road of adding an include vlan_list.yml outside of this task but no familiar with out to do that.

Actual results are

`The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\n`

I need the create a single vnic template with multiple vlans defined in that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another engineer i work with was able to solve the question.  By the way the variables are laid out we were able to easily just change the code

Change this:

```
    vlans_list: 
     - name: "{{ item.1.name }}"
       native: "{{ item.1.native }}"
       state: "{{ item.1.present }}"
```

To this:

```
    vlans_list: "{{ item.vlans_list }}"
```

Full Code listed below.

```
- name: Add vNIC Templates
  ucs_vnic_template:
    hostname: "{{ ucs_manager_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ ucs_manager_username }}"
    password: "{{ ucs_manager_password }}"
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    fabric: "{{ item.fabric }}"
    mac_pool: "{{ item.mac_pool }}"
    mtu: "{{ item.mtu }}"
    org_dn: "{{ item.org_dn }}"
    redundancy_type: "{{ item.redundancy_type }}"
    state: "{{ item.state }}"
    template_type: "{{ item.template_type }}"
    vlans_list: "{{ item.vlans_list }}" 
  with_items:
     - "{{ vnic_templates }}"
```